# This code runs in Bracket editor but does not work in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, adobe-brackets

I've this code:

In the head:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mostrarPlay").click(function(){
        alert('Hello');
    });
});
```

and in the body

```
<a class="btn" id='mostrarPlay' href='#'>Play</a>
```

It Works when pulse the Run icon in Brackets Editor, but when use Google Chrome, does not work.

Any idea?

Best Regards

Comment: Do you load the jQuery library in the head? Maybe it is automatically added by Bracket but isn't present in your html (this is also a common error when people copy & paste from JSFiddle)?! Can you add the full header with all the `<script>` tags? Any errors in the Chrome Dev Tools?

Comment: <!Doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Máquina Total</title>
 <link href="./css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <!-- Get jQuery -->
 <script src="./js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/jquery.countdown.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
 <script src="./js/typed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: No error in Console chrome DEV

Comment: When you click on Run, Brackets hosts the websites locally, for you. Are you perhaps running it from the filesystem or after the hosting is stopped??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Its working fine on my end check the code below:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <a class="btn" id='mostrarPlay' href='#'>Play</a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#mostrarPlay").click(function(){
    alert('Hello');
  });
});
</script>

</body>
<html>
```

**Alerts are showing properly in google chrome. If you have any questions let me know**